# Property [id] does not exist in this collection instance when I try to setup the edit function

Tags: laravel-5

I get this:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Property [id] does not exist in this collection instance.

I have been looking around and I tried a few different fixes but I still haven't found the answer. This is what I have so far... I can't find what's causing the issue so I need little help...

PostsController.php

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    $categories = Category::all();
    $cats = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category){
            $cats[$category->id] = $category->title;
            }

    return view('posts.edit')->withPost($post)->withCategories($cats);
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
{!! Form::model($post, ['route' => ['PostsController@update', $post->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
                         <div class="col-md-4">           
                                    <div class'form-group'>
                                        {{ Form::label('title', 'Title')}}
                                        {{ Form::text('title', $post->title, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title'])}}
                                    </div>
                         </div>

                         <div class="col-md-4">           
                                    <div class'form-group'>
                                        {{ Form::label('slug', 'Slug')}}
                                        {{ Form::text('slug', $post->slug, ['class' => 'form-control ', 'placeholder' => 'Slug', 'required' =>'', 'minlength' => '5', 'maxlength' => '255'])}}
                                    </div>
                         </div>

                         <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class'form-group'>
                                        {{ Form::label('category_id', 'Category :')}}
                                        {{ Form::select('category_id', $categories, $post->categoty_id, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                                    </div>
                         </div>
                 </div>

            <div class="row post_row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class'form-group'>
                                {{ Form::label('body', 'Body')}}
                                {!! Form::textarea('body', '$post->body', ['id' => 'article-ckeditor', 'class' => 'form-control space', 'placeholder' => 'Body Text'])!!}
                            </div>
                </div>
           </div>

                    <div class'form-group' style="padding-top: 20px">
                     {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
                     {!! Form::close() !!}
                     </div>
```

Comment: At a glance, I don't see it. But find anywhere you're accessing `->id`, and make sure the variable you're accessing it from isn't a collection. Or, if it is, perform a loop. I see you accessing `$post->id` and `$category->id`, and both of those, by both naming convention and code definition, *shouldn't* be collections...

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should really take advantage from Collection methods : `$cats = $categories->pluck('title', 'id')` ;-)

Comment: I resolved the issue with the "ErrorException (E_ERROR) Property [id] does not exist in this collection instance".  I had to change to <a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a> 
from 
<a href="/posts/{{$post->slug}}/edit" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>

Comment: But now I have this issue, "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PostsController::edit(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected", I looked up the issue and I read that I needed to fix the Route::get to something like this;

Route::get('/show/{id}', 'PostsController@show'); 

But im using the Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController'); method, so Im not sure how to resolved this issue? 

If this is a question I should post as a separate question I apologize but I looking to see if anyone had any guidance to resolve this issue!